# Switch case statement inside if statement doesn't show multiple choice

Tags: android

I cannot get the four multiple choice buttons and the question textView to display text. What happens is there is an intent transferred over with a selected category "who" or "what". That category is compared with the "who" and "what" if statements. If it is one of them then it is supposed to post the question and run through the ten question. I am using a switch case inside the if statement to help distinguish what button was clicked and move on. When I run the emulator it gets to the screen with four multiple choice buttons but nothing is display on the text or text view.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<QuestionsTable> whoQuesList;
List<QuestionsTable> whatQuesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
QuestionsTable currentWhatQ;
QuestionsTable currentWhoQ;
Button btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD;
Button butSkip;
TextView txtQuestion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    butSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    whoQuesList = db.getAllWhos();
    whatQuesList = db.getAllWhos();
    currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
    currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
}
    public void onClickQuestion(View txtViewQuestion) {
        Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
        int c = d.getInt("category");
        String category = Integer.toString(c);

        if ("Who".equals(category)) {
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewQuestion);
        btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionA);
        btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionB);
        btnC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionC);
        btnD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionD);
        setQuestionView();
        switch (txtViewQuestion.getId()) {
            case btnOptionA:
                if (currentWhoQ.getAnswer().equals(btnA.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                break;

            case btnOptionB:
                if (currentWhoQ.getAnswer().equals(btnB.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                break;
            case btnOptionC:
                if (currentWhoQ.getAnswer().equals(btnC.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }

                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                break;
            case R.id.btnOptionD:
                if (currentWhoQ.getAnswer().equals(btnD.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                break;

        }
    }


    if ("What".equals(category)) {
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        whoQuesList = db.getAllWhos();
        whatQuesList = db.getAllWhos();
        currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
        currentWhoQ = whoQuesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewQuestion);
        btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionA);
        btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionB);
        btnC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionC);
        btnD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOptionD);
        setWhatQuestionView();
        switch (txtViewQuestion.getId()) {
            case btnOptionA:
                if (currentWhatQ.getAnswer().equals(btnA.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                break;

            case btnOptionB:
                if (currentWhatQ.getAnswer().equals(btnB.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                break;
            case btnOptionC:
                if (currentWhatQ.getAnswer().equals(btnC.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }

                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                break;
            case R.id.btnOptionD:
                if (currentWhatQ.getAnswer().equals(btnD.getText())) {
                    score++;
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentWhatQ = whatQuesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                break;

        }
    }

}

public void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentWhoQ.getQuestion());
    btnA.setText(currentWhoQ.getMultipleChoiceA());
    btnB.setText(currentWhoQ.getMultipleChoiceB());
    btnC.setText(currentWhoQ.getMultipleChoiceC());
    btnD.setText(currentWhoQ.getMultipleChoiceD());
    qid++;
}

public void setWhatQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentWhatQ.getQuestion());
    btnA.setText(currentWhatQ.getMultipleChoiceA());
    btnB.setText(currentWhatQ.getMultipleChoiceB());
    btnC.setText(currentWhatQ.getMultipleChoiceC());
    btnD.setText(currentWhatQ.getMultipleChoiceD());
    qid++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
    int c = d.getInt("category");
    String category = Integer.toString(c);

    if ("Who".equals(category)) {
```

What is the value of c? How could it ever equal "Who" or "What"?

And like others have said, use the full ID of the buttons in the switch statements.

```
case R.id.btnOptionA:
```

instead of

```
case btnOptionA:
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, what type of Data your txtViewQuestion is...
The Switch Statement Works perfectly with primitive Data types...

If you try to call the Name of the Button Variable, this will Not Work because a program only works with memory adress, so Java will Not be able to give you the name of your object (if its a Button)

To solve this, you could Pass a Parameter to the Methods (for example int)
0 for the first button
1 for the second button
2 for the third...
And then you could "Switch" this Parameter

Answer (score 0):

What is btnOptionA, btnOptionB and btnOptionC?  txtViewQuestion.getId() return an Integer, in case tag you should use R.id.btnOptionA, R.id.btnOptionB, R.id.btnOptionC...